# I am having trouble trying to authenticate Google SDK using cygwin

Tags: bash, cygwin

I am trying to install SDK using Cygwin as instructed here https://developers.google.com/cloud/sdk/#Quick_Start

after Cygwin is installed I follow the guide and then try to authenticate using the `gcloud auth login command`, but get the following returned and do not know how to remedy.

```
> $ gcloud auth login
> -bash: gcloud: command not found
```

sorry I am not that technical, so I am sorry this is fairly basic, but I have tried searching and can't find a solution, so thanks in anticipation for any help

Comment: Have you considered installing gcloud? The error message says it right in your face.

Comment: yes I have 'curl https://sdk.cloud.google.com | bash' and then restarted cygwin

Comment: BTW this is the contents of the directory I am running the command from and as you can see it shows Gcloud `$ ls -F
gcloud auth login  google-cloud-sdk/  y/
`

Answer (score 3):

The command may not be in the `$PATH`so you need to use the path to the command.  You can run a command from the current folder with`./` in front:

```
./gcloud auth login
```

Comment: its not in your path, you can likely find it in your home directory, assuming that you installed with the default settings... `~/google-cloud-sdk/bin% ./gcloud auth login` should work

Answer (score 3):

You should verify that your path is setup correctly...youre using cygwin, so i presume its a windows machine...

see here for details on updating the path in various windows environments... 
https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml

For bash Shell: 
 1. Edit the startup file (~/ .bashrc)
 2. Modify PATH variable: PATH="$PATH":~/google-cloud-sdk/bin
 3. export PATH

in unix/linux/mac you could run

```
export PATH="$HOME/google-cloud-sdk/bin:$PATH"
```

Answer (score 1):

Download and install Google Cloud SDK by running the following command in your shell or Terminal:

```
curl https://sdk.cloud.google.com | bash
```

(Or, you can download google-cloud-sdk.zip or google-cloud-sdk.tar.gz, unpack it, and launch the ./google-cloud-sdk/install.sh script.)

Restart your shell or Terminal.

Authenticate to Google Cloud Platform by running `gcloud auth login`.

Comment: This is not helpful, all you have done is copy and pasted the quick start guide, that he provided in the OP.  He is having troubles beyond this point. obviously.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this same issue (and even ended up here off a google search too). But for me the issue was solved by breaking apart the command google gives [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/#debubu) in Step 4:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install google-cloud-sdk
```

into separate commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install google-cloud-sdk
```

Since there were a couple of packages unrelated to the Google SDK that failed to download during the `apt-get update` command, the only guess I have is that stopped the command on the other side of the logical `&&` from executing.

When I executed the second command by itself instead, the `google-cloud-sdk` package installed as a new package, so I assume the compound command from before failed.

After this the instructions in Step 5 (to execute `gcloud auth login`) was successful.

Hope this helps anyone else on Ubuntu/Debian for whom the other solutions didn't work.